# Fake distributed computation - secure summation on IRLS for binary logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, irls, distributed-computing

I am attempting to perform an IRLS algorithm to estimate regression parameters for a logistic regression model.
This is the algorithm that I am following

1. Select initial values for the regression parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {old }}$
2. Calculate the $p\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{i}, \boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {old }}\right)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x_{i}^{T} \beta^{\text {ord }}}}, i=1, \ldots, n$
3. Calculate the diagonal weight matrix $W$ with elements $p\left(x_{i}, \beta^{o l d}\right)\left(1-p\left(x_{i}, \beta^{\text {old }}\right)\right)$.
4. Calculate the Gradient vector and Hessian matrix
   (a) $\frac{\partial l(\boldsymbol{\beta})}{\partial \beta}=\boldsymbol{X}^{T}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{p})$
   (b) $\frac{\partial t(\beta)}{\partial \beta \theta \beta^{1}}=-\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{W} \mathbf{X}$
5. Calculate $\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {new }}=\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {old }}+\left(\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{W} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1} \boldsymbol{X}^{T}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{p})$ or $\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {new }}=\left(X^{T} W X\right)^{-1} X^{T} W z$, with adjusted response $\mathbf{z}=\left(\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {old }}+\mathbf{W}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{p})\right)$
6. Set $\beta^{\text {old }}=\beta^{\text {new }}$
7. Repeat steps (2) to (6) until convergence.

The catch is I have to do a sort of fake distributed computation scenario. So my main data set $X$ has 300 observations which I split up into 3 smaller data sets consisting of 100 observations each.
$$\mathbf{X}=\left[\begin{array}{c}X_{1} \\ X_{2}\\ X_{3}\end{array}\right]$$

Now from what I understand the idea behind [secure summation](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Ejerry/Papers/jcgs05.pdf) is as follow
$$\left(\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{W} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^3 \left(\mathbf{X_i}^{T} \mathbf{W_i} \mathbf{X_i}\right)^{-1}$$ and $$\boldsymbol{X}^{T}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{p}) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \boldsymbol{X_i}^{T}(\boldsymbol{y_i}-\boldsymbol{p_i}) $$

So what I am doing looks a bit like this

1. Select initial values for the regression parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {old }}$
2. Calculate the $p=\frac{1}{1+e^{-X_{i} \beta^{\text {ord }}}}, i=1, \ldots, 3$
3. Calculate the diagonal weight matrix $W_i$ for i=1 $\ldots$ 3, with elements $p\left(x_{i}, \beta^{o l d}\right)\left(1-p\left(x_{i}, \beta^{\text {old }}\right)\right)$.
4. Calculate the Gradient vector and Hessian matrix for i=1 $\ldots$ 3
   (a) $\boldsymbol{X_i}^{T}(\boldsymbol{y_i}-\boldsymbol{p_i})$
   (b) $\left(\mathbf{X_i}^{T} \mathbf{W_i} \mathbf{X_i}\right)^{-1}$
5. $$\left(\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{W} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^3 \left(\mathbf{X_i}^{T} \mathbf{W_i} \mathbf{X_i}\right)^{-1}$$ and $$\boldsymbol{X}^{T}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{p}) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \boldsymbol{X_i}^{T}(\boldsymbol{y_i}-\boldsymbol{p_i}) $$
6. Calculate $\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {new }}=\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {old }}+\left(\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{W} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1} \boldsymbol{X}^{T}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{p})$ or $\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {new }}=\left(X^{T} W X\right)^{-1} X^{T} W z$, with adjusted response $\mathbf{z}=\left(\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\beta}^{\text {old }}+\mathbf{W}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{p})\right)$
7. Set $\beta^{\text {old }}=\beta^{\text {new }}$
8. Repeat steps (2) to (6) until convergence.

Here is my R code along with some generated data

```
age <- round(runif(10, 18, 80))
xb <- -9 + 0.2*age
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-xb))
y <- rbinom(n = 10, size = 1, prob = p)

lst = split(df, (0:nrow(df) %/% 100)) 
df_1 <- lst$`0`
df_2 <- lst$`1`
df_3 <- lst$`2`

#########IRLS##########
bho <- matrix(0,2,1)
#DF 1
x_1 <- cbind(matrix(1,100,1),df_1$age)

#DF 2
x_2 <- cbind(matrix(1,100,1),df_2$age)

#DF 3
x_3 <- cbind(matrix(1,100,1),df_3$age)

for (i in 1:30) {
  
  #DF 1
  p_fit_1 <- 1/(1 + exp(-(x_1%*%bho)))
  wp_1 <- as.vector(p_fit_1*(1-p_fit_1))
  w_1 <- diag(wp_1)
  
  hes_1 <- inv(t(x_1)%*%w_1%*%x_1)
  grad_1 <- (t(x_1)%*%(df_1$y-p_fit_1))
  
  #DF 2
  p_fit_2 <- 1/(1 + exp(-(x_2%*%bho)))
  wp_2 <- as.vector(p_fit_2*(1-p_fit_2))
  w_2 <- diag(wp_2)

  hes_2 <- inv(t(x_2)%*%w_2%*%x_2)
  grad_2 <- (t(x_2)%*%(df_2$y-p_fit_2))

  #DF 3
  p_fit_3 <- 1/(1 + exp(-(x_3%*%bho)))
  wp_3 <- as.vector(p_fit_3*(1-p_fit_3))
  w_3 <- diag(wp_3)

  hes_3 <- inv(t(x_3)%*%w_3%*%x_3)
  grad_3 <- (t(x_3)%*%(df_3$y-p_fit_3))

  #Put it together now
  hes <- hes_1+hes_2+hes_3
  grad <- grad_1+grad_2+grad_3
  
  bhn <- bho + hes%*%grad
  
  chnge = max(abs(bhn-bho))
  if (chnge<1E-3) break
  bho <- bhn
  
}

xbn <- x%*%bhn
pn <- 1/(1 + exp(-xbn))
######################
```

But my values simply do not converge and I sometimes get an error saying `Error in Inverse(X, tol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), ...) :  X is numerically singular.` Am I implementing the algorithm wrong?
Would anyone be able to assist, please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing the inverse of the Hessian for each partition of your data, first sum all the Hessians together, and then take the inverse of the sum of the Hessians.

Isolating only the definition of the Hessians from your code, that would be

```
#DF1
hes_1 <- t(x_1)%*%w_1%*%x_1

#DF2
hes_2 <- t(x_2)%*%w_2%*%x_2

#DF3
hes_3 <- t(x_3)%*%w_3%*%x_3

#Put it together now
hes <- inv(hes_1 + hes_2 + hes_3)
```

Invert the sum of the Hessians, not the individual Hessians. Your parameters will then reach convergence :)